# React component logs object and then logs undefined on same object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am an extreme newcomer to development, and as such I might be missing something obvious. I am busy creating a simple React app to display an array of objects. I have hard coded the general idea of an array in the parent component and passed it through to the child components. However, when I try logging the prop to console, it first appears as the object should, then logs again as undefined. This is making it really difficult to call an Object.keys() function on it and try map it to an array.

Below is an example of the code:

```
export class Parent extends React.Component() {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      arr: []
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <child array={this.state.arr} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Then the child follows:

```
export class Child extends React.Component() {
  renderArray() {
    let arr = this.props.array;
    console.log(arr);
    return Object.keys(arr).map(arrayItem => {
      let title = arr[arrayItem];
      return <li key={title.id}> {title.name}</li>
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.renderArray()}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

If I call console.log on arr object in the child component, it returns the props correctly. But then right after that it logs a second instance of 'undefined'.

EDIT: Lots of comments about empty array. Please see code below.

Here is the parent component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

import { SearchBar } from '../SearchBar/SearchBar.js';
import { SearchResults } from '../SearchResults/SearchResults.js';
import { Playlist } from '../Playlist/Playlist.js';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchResults: [
        {
          "id": 2011,
          "name": 'What Makes A Man',
          "artist": 'Man As Machine',
          "album": 'Nothing but a thing'
        },
        {
          "id": 2056,
          "name": 'Pushpin',
          "artist": 'Man As Machine',
          "album": 'Patterns'
        },
        {
          "id": 2099,
          "name": 'Zombie',
          "artist": 'Man As Machine',
          "album": 'Patterns'
        }
      ],
      playlistName: ''
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Ja<span className="highlight">mmm</span>ing</h1>
        <div className="App">
        <SearchBar />
          <div className="App-playlist">
            <SearchResults searchResults={this.state.searchResults}/>
            <Playlist />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Then I have the searchResults component (child):

```
import React from 'react';
import './SearchResults.css';

import { Tracklist } from '../Tracklist/Tracklist.js';

export class SearchResults extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div className="SearchResults">
        <h2>Results</h2>
        <Tracklist tracks={this.props.searchResults}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

and finally the tracklist component:

```
import React from 'react';
import './Tracklist.css';

import { Track } from '../Track/Track.js';

export class Tracklist extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  renderTrackList() {
    let tracks = this.props.tracks;
    console.log(tracks);
    return Object.keys(tracks).map(track => {
      let trackItem = tracks[track];
      return <Track key={trackItem.id} track={trackItem}
    })
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div className="TrackList">
        {this.renderTrackList()}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Here is the searchBar component:

```
import React from 'react';
import './SearchBar.css';

export class SearchBar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="SearchBar">
        <input placeholder="Enter A Song, Album, or Artist" />
        <a>SEARCH</a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and here is the Track component:

```
import React from 'react';
import './Track.css';

export class Track extends React.Component {
  renderAction (isRemoval) {
    if (this.props.isRemoval){
      return <a className="Track-action" onClick={this.removeTrack}>-</a>
    } else {
      return <a className="Track-action" onClick={this.addTrack}>+</a>
    }
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div className="Track">
        <div className="Track-information">
          <h3>{this.props.track.name}</h3>
          <p>{this.props.track.artist} | {this.props.track.album}</p>
        </div>
        <a className="Track-action">{this.renderAction}</a>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: How is arr array looks like ? Seems you are passing empty array from parent

Comment: It is an array of objects.

Comment: arr: [{},{},{}]

Comment: you had a few issues - think you are looking for something like this - https://codesandbox.io/s/64vno8z9nw

Answer (score 0):

you're working with an array of something, and `Object.keys()` is for iterate on object property keys.

You can iterate in your array directly with `map()`.

```
return arr.map(arrayItem => {
      let title = arr[arrayItem];
      return <li key={title.id}> {title.title}</li>
})
```

Or you can do it better because here you are missing the `<ul>` element

```
export class Child extends React.Component() {
  renderArray() {
    if(this.props.array && this.props.array.length >0){
      return (
        <ul>
          {this.props.array.map(item => <li key={item.id}>{item.title}</li>)
        </ul>
      )
    }
    return 'No item in array.'

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.renderArray()}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

You've to put some data in your array

```
this.state={
 arr:[
   {id:1,title:"item 1"},
   {id:2,title:"item 2"}
 ]
}
```

Comment: I read up on that. However, it says that even though I'm passing an array, it registers as an object as its passed through props. So I need to use the handler Object.keys() to seperate the object into a managable array.

Comment: Nop, the state is made with object properties, but here you are accessing a property value of your props/state, who is a table so you have to iterate the table and not the object.

Comment: Didn't work. I also tried the other suggestion of using double quotes around my array identifiers.

Comment: You've to initiate your array in the parent component. It display 'No item in array' ?

Answer (score 0):

Child component be Child but not child when you call it. Please try below solution

```
  import Child from “./Child”;
  export class Parent extends React.Component() {
     constructor(props) {
         super(props);
         this.state = {
              arr: [
       {"id":1, name:"test"}, {"id": 2, "name": "test2"}
           ]
          }
      }

  render() {
     return (
         <div>
           <Child array={this.state.arr} />
         </div>
        )
    }
  }
```

Child component

```
 export class Child extends React.Component() {
       renderArray = (array) => {
           return array.map(item=> (
                <li key={item.id}> {item.name}</li>
            )
         }

     render() {
        const {array} = this.props;
         return (
           <div>
              <ul>
             {this.renderArray(array)}

             </ul>
         </div>
         )
      }
    }
```

Please excuse me for wrong double quotes because I am answering on my phone

Comment: You answer is like mine and you forgot <ul> element your return statement is wrong

Comment: Yeah I didn’t notice that. Thank you